# Route resolve promise in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Using a route resolve allows the promise to resolve before the controller logic executes, so I want to resolve my promise in the ui-router configuration. I have 3 files: **app.js**, **main.controller.js** and **products.service.js**

**app.js**

```
angular.module('app',[
    'Products',
    'ui.router'
])
    .config(config);

config.$inject = ['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider'];

function config($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
    // For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/products");

    // Now set up the states
    $stateProvider
        .state('productsState', {
            url: "/products",
            templateUrl: "views/products.html",
            controller: "MainController as Main",
            resolve: MainController.resolve
        });
}
```

**main.controller.js**

```
angular.module('app')

.controller('MainController', MainController);

MainController.resolve = {
    _products: ['ProductsService', function (ProductsService) {
        return ProductsService.getProducts();
    }]
};

MainController.$inject = ['_products'];

function MainController(_products){
    var vm = this;

    vm.test = 'Angular 1.4.8';
    vm.products = _products;
}
```

**products.service.js**

```
angular.module('Products',[])
    .factory('ProductsService', ProductsService);

ProductsService.$inject = ['$http'];

function ProductsService($http){
    return {
      getProducts:getProducts
    };

    function getProducts(){
        return $http.get('some-url').then(function(response){
            return response.data;
        });
    }
}
```

> Unknown provider: _productsProvider <- _products <- MainController

Comment: I first noticed that you don't have `ProductsService` included in your controller. Could this be the problem?

Comment: @PankajParkar yes, top line code from app.js

Comment: @thepio I injected it also in the MainController but same result ....

Comment: It could be the _ having some special meaning but I'm not 100% on that. I'd try and simplify your resolve and work out from there. For starters don't inject anything into your resolve and just return an object. Then inject the product service but still return an object. You'll probably find that the injection into the resolve isn't working correctly, when you fix that the rest will just work

Comment: Also, remove the _ from the resolve parameter, it is a quick thing to check, just in case.

Comment: Also, ensure that your products JS file is loaded before your app.js.

Comment: @BenCr I did, I started with this guide : https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md , but still doesn't work

Comment: Everything looks reasonable, create a plunkr. or similar.